# Execute the command "UPDATE" which is in the variable CLOB

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I keep some commands in CLOB format. I have the command "update WAYBILLS set TARE = 1212 where  EXTERNAL_ID = 1212". I want to do it by calling in the process. I want to perform the actions described in this command. But I do not understand how, I will be grateful for the help

```
declare 
     l_clob           CLOB;  
     v_sql            CLOB;
     
BEGIN  
     v_sql := 'update WAYBILLS set TARE = 1212 where  EXTERNAL_ID = 1212';
END ;
```

Comment: look at EXECUTE IMMEDIATE

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to execute dynamic SQL is to use EXECUTE IMMEDIATE. Use bind variables.

```
DECLARE
   v_sql  CLOB;
   v_id   PLS_INTEGER := 1212;
BEGIN
  v_sql := 'UPDATE waybills SET tare = :id WHERE external_id = :id';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE(v_sql) USING v_id, v_id;
END;
/
```

If your statements are longer than 32k, then you have to deal with DBMS_SQL.

You can find more information for example here: [Database PL/SQL Language Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/lnpls/EXECUTE-IMMEDIATE-statement.html#GUID-C3245A95-B85B-4280-A01F-12307B108DC8)